# Angular router event when page returned to

Tags: angular, angular-router

I need to reload some content after the user returns back to a page.

I believe this would work using something like the below:

```
ngOnInit() {
}
```

But

```
ngOnReturn() {
}
```

Is there anything like this in `angular` to let me have that?

Small example:

On a page with some content, click a button, navigate away, user does something and either hits back or I go back using the router, I need an event to fire so I know to reload the page content.